# How to insert data to temp Table in stored procedure with another procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, entity

I want insert data to procedure 2 AddTempData from procedure 1 AddID1. But i can't do it.

```
create proc AddID1
as
begin
declare @TempData table
(
    ID int
)
insert into @TempData select P.Id from Product as P 
select * from @TempData
end

create proc AddTempData
as
begin
declare @TempDataID table
(
  IDTemp int
)
insert into @TempDataID exec AddID1 
select * from @TempDataID
end
```

Comment: What do you mean with "But i can't do it."?

Comment: I want insert data to procedure 2 AddTempData from procedure 1 AddID1.But when i select * from @TempDataID IDTemp is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a complete working example.

As far as your code.....maybe try

```
insert into @TempDataID (IDTemp)
   exec AddID1
```

But the below are working examples:

```
/*  START TSQL CODE */

/*  Stored Procedure Definition */

Use Northwind
GO


IF EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
    WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = N'PROCEDURE' and ROUTINE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' and ROUTINE_NAME = N'uspOrderDetailsByCustomerId'  
    )
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspOrderDetailsByCustomerId]
END


GO

CREATE Procedure dbo.uspOrderDetailsByCustomerId
(
  @CustomerID nchar(5)
)
AS

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON



        SELECT 
            c.CustomerID, c.CompanyName /*,c.ContactName,c.ContactTitle,c.[Address],c.City,c.Region,c.PostalCode,c.Country ,c.Phone,c.Fax */
        FROM 
            Customers c 
            JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID /* this join here just to provide extra rows for the example */
        WHERE 
            c.CustomerID = @CustomerID

END
```

Now the populate, first with a #Temp table.

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempCustomer') IS NOT NULL
    begin
            drop table #TempCustomer
    end


    CREATE TABLE #TempCustomer
    ( 
      [CustomerID] nchar(5)
    , [CompanyName] nvarchar(40)
    )

INSERT INTO #TempCustomer ( [CustomerID] , [CompanyName])
exec dbo.uspOrderDetailsByCustomerId 'ALFKI'

Select * from #TempCustomer


    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempCustomer') IS NOT NULL
    begin
            drop table #TempCustomer
    end
```

You can also use a @Variable Table ( like your example )

```
declare @VariableTableCustomer table
    ( 
      [CustomerID] nchar(5)
    , [CompanyName] nvarchar(40)
    )

INSERT INTO @VariableTableCustomer ( [CustomerID] , [CompanyName])
exec dbo.uspCustomerByCustomerId 'ALFKI'

Select * from @VariableTableCustomer
```

I just ran all your code (minus one line), it works:

```
--drop proc AddID1
GO

create proc AddID1
as
begin
declare @TempData table
(
    ID int
)


insert into @TempData 
/*select P.Id from Product as P */
/* note, i'm commenting out the above line and using the below line since I don't have your db table/rows */
select 333 union all select 444 union all select 555


select * from @TempData
end


GO



/* make sure hte procedure works...as you desire..before trying to stuff it into a temp or varaible table */
EXEC AddID1

GO




--drop proc AddTempData
GO


create proc AddTempData
as
begin
declare @TempDataID table
(
  IDTemp int
)
insert into @TempDataID (IDTemp) exec AddID1 
select 'Inside_AddTempData' as MyPlace , * from @TempDataID
end

GO

EXEC AddTempData
```

Comment: 'ALFKI' what is this?

Comment: insert into @TempDataID (IDTemp) exec AddID1 . I tried but when I select * from TempDataID, IDTemp is null

Comment: ALFKI is for my Northwind example.  Note the "use Northwind".  Northwind is a db that Microsoft distributes and most people have it...its good for writing examples against......

Comment: Run " exec AddID1" by itself and see if you get the desired results....before attempting to put it in a variable or temp table.

Comment: Run "exec AddID1" I see expected results, but TempDataID not have data.

Comment: I appended my answer.  Outside of "select P.Id from Product as P", its a complete working example.